# Get screen resolution of mac OSX login screen

Tags: macos

Is it possible to get the resolution of the login screen (Snow leopard and lion) from an app (daemon) that would be running while the login screen is up?

I am wondering if it is a special case because I believe there is no access to the window server from the login screen, but I am new to the mac so it is very possible that I have some things wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

CGDisplayBounds(CGMainDisplayID()).size.height, CGDisplayBounds(CGMainDisplayID()).size.width